# How can i use textfield widget in a string?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to use textfield or textformfield in a String.
Ex: Beautiful ____ flutter.
String value can have more than one word.
How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Row` like so

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        '..',
        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(child: TextFormField(/*...*/)),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        '..',
        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. String value can have 30 words or more. So this value will be multiline. I want to change a specific word with textfield in this string value. This word can be any word in String value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget is the going to give the best solution. Unfortunately I could only get it to work with a single line of text. Once the inputed text gets too long it forces the TextField onto its own line.

```dart
    RichText( 
      text: const TextSpan(
        text: 'Beautiful ',
        children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0),
                    isDense: true,
                    hintText: '     ',
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null),
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(text: ' flutter'),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Note: Edited to answer the question with a TextField instead of a TextSpan widget

Comment: Thanks for your answer. myString should be a textfield widget in my case. I want to click textfield and write something in Text widget.

Comment: Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Also, this may potentially be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65233481/11920147

Answer (score 1):

Well, guess I was wrong. I commented saying this was impossible, but it was simply me not knowing the right widget for the job, which is `WidgetSpan`.
Extending what @developer extraordinare [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70681847/2501858), you can put `WidgetSpan` in the `TextSpan` tree inside a `RichText` widget, like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'Beautiful',
            children: [
              WidgetSpan(child: TextFormField()),
              const TextSpan(text: ' flutter'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      
    );
  }
```

[image: almost live example from dartpad]

The results probably aren't as nice as you'd like, but it gets the job done. You probably have just to fiddle with `SizedBox`, constraints and the such to make the editable `TextFormField` fit nicely in the text.

Comment: That awkward moment when you read the question wrong and gave an answer to the wrong question but you were still close enough to help someone else give the right answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @malozyali-Yalçın if my answer solved your problem, can you please mark it as the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: it didn't solve my problem.